# MongoDB update $pull operator is not removing item from array

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in MongoDB.
And want to remove an item from array.

My "users" collection is an array of objects.

When I type:

```
db.users.find({"tasks.task_id" : "h58sjIdj3jJZ"}).pretty()
```

in mongo shell, I get this result:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5955b45b7a4bf40544019359"),
  "profile" : {
    "name" : "Morning bay",
    "email" : "morbay232@google.su",
    "phone" : "+1-641-155-88-84",
    "description" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit"
  },
  "tasks" : [
    {
      "task_id" : "h58sjIdj3jJY",
      "time" : "11:15 AM",
      "date" : "07/01/2017",
      "description" : "Make 1st call to John White"
    },
    {
      "task_id" : "h58sjIdj3jJZ",
      "time" : "14:30 PM",
      "date" : "07/09/2017",
      "description" : "Send certificate and make Another call to J.White"
    }
  ],
  "progress" : [
    {
      "isActive" : "",
      "description" : ""
    }
  ]
}
```

So, every item in my collection looks like this.
And it's ok.

But now I want to remove one item from "tasks" array in one of users items.

I type:

```
db.users.update({}, {$pull : {"tasks" : {"task_id" : "h58sjIdj3jJZ"}}});
```

an get this result:

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

I read documentation and examples in it look similar, so I don't understand where is an error.

Comment: It should works. What is your mongodb version ?

Comment: Can you add { multi:true } as 3rd argument of your update ? `db.users.update({}, {$pull : {"tasks" : {"task_id" : "h58sjIdj3jJZ"}}}, { multi:true } );`

Comment: already tried, but it doesn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're using `{}` in update search query what by default means `find any document`, and then you're modifying its tasks list `{$pull : {"tasks" : {"task_id" : "h58sjIdj3jJZ"}}}`.

So, probably another document is being modified (which may or may not contain task of id `h58sjIdj3jJZ` but in that case its irrelevant whether it has it or not)

You have 2 options:
use:

`db.users.update({}, {$pull : {"tasks" : {"task_id" : "h58sjIdj3jJZ"}}}, { multi: true });`

what eventually touches every document in db,

OR

make search query more specific (provide id or look for item with task_id in tasks)

`db.users.update({ "tasks.task_id": "h58sjIdj3jJZ"}, {$pull : {"tasks" : {"task_id" : "h58sjIdj3jJZ"}}});`

Comment: Yes! I used `db.users.update({ "tasks.task_id": "h58sjIdj3jJZ"}, {$pull : {"tasks" : {"task_id" : "h58sjIdj3jJZ"}}})` and it helped! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I tested it on a MongoDB Terminal Online and your query correctly pulled the document.

Here is the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giwOl.jpg).

Are you experiencing this issue with the shell or using an ODM (like Mongoose)?

Comment: I use MongoJS instead of Mongoose. And yes, there is the same issue. It doesn't remove an item from tasks array.